# Let $K = $ algebraic numbers. Then is $\operatorname{Span}_K(\pi, \pi^2, \dots)$ a vector space of transcendentals?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

$V = {\rm Span}_K(\pi, \pi^2, \dots)$ is clearly a $K$-vector space.  If we let $K = \Bbb{Q}$ temporarily, then every element of $V$ is transcendental as it's a finite linear combination $Q(X), \ X = \pi$ of the $\pi^i$ and thus can't equal an algebraic $a$ or else for the polynomial $P(a) = 0$ over $K$, we'd have $P(Q(X))= 0$ at $\pi$.

But what if we let $K = $ some algebraic exension of $\Bbb{Q}$ or even the field of all algebraic numbers.  Can we prove a similar statement?

Edit: The only exception to the first pargraph is $0 \in V$ which is not trans.

Comment: If $r$ is algebraic over $F$ and $F$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $r$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @egreg link or proof?

Comment: @EnjoysMath Do you understand the proof that the algebraic numbers are closed under addition and multiplication?  You can adapt that to show that they're closed under 'composition' - that any root of an equation with algebraic coefficients is itself algebraic.  That gives your result.

Comment: Adjoin the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $r$ over $F$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. Since they are alegebraic over  $\mathbb{Q}$, the extension $\mathbb{Q}(r)/ \mathbb{Q}$ is finite, hence algebraic.

Comment: Every element of $K$ is an exception to the first paragraph. That algebraicity is transitive is a fairly basic fact covered pretty soon in algebraic number theory or field theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $r\in\mathbb{C}$ be algebraic over $F$, where $F$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ which is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $r$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Proof. Let $f(X)=a_0+a_1X+\dots+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+X^n\in F[X]$ be the minimum polynomial of $r$ over $F$. Then $r$ is also algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}[a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}]$, which amounts to say that $\mathbb{Q}[[a_0,\dots,a_{n-1},r]$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}[a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}]$. Since $a_i$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, we have the chain of finite extensions
$$
\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}[a_0]\subseteq\mathbb{Q}[a_0,a_1]\subseteq
\dots\subseteq\mathbb{Q}[a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}]
$$
so also $\mathbb{Q}[a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},r]$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore $r$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.